# How to use data from the updated table in a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger, ora-04091

So I have these two tables:

```
create table CURRENCY
(
     name VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) PRIMARY KEY,
     value NUMBER(6,2)
);

create table EXCHANGE_RATE
(
     currency1 references CURRENCY(name),
     currency2 references CURRENCY(name),
     price NUMBER(6,2),
     PRIMARY KEY(currency1, currency2)
);
```

Whenever I insert a new `CURRENCY`, I want to create new `EXCHANGE_RATES` between all previous `CURRIENCIES`and a new one. Let's say I have just one currency in my table:

```
INSERT INTO CURRENCY VALUES("EURO", 2.0)
```

And now want to insert a new one:

```
INSERT INTO CURRENCY VALUES("DOLLAR", 1.0)
```

My goal is to insert into `EXCHANGE_RATE` rows:

```
"EURO", "DOLLAR", 2.0
"DOLLAR", "EURO", 0.5
```

What is the best way to do is? I've tried to use `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` 
trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_currency
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON CURRENCY
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_RATE (currency1, currency2, price)
SELECT name, :new.name, price/:new.price
FROM CURRENCY;

INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_RATE (currency1, currency2, price)
SELECT  :new.name, name, :new.price/price
FROM CURRENCY;

END;
/
```

but it doesn't work since I have to query `CURRENCY` table, that is beeing updated and I just end up with ORA-04091.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't query the table that caused a trigger to fire inside the trigger itself.

If I were you, I will consider to use stored procedure approach. Just move your insert script into a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INS_CURRENCY (p_currency varchar2, p_price number) as
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CURRENCY VALUES(p_currency , p_Price);

    INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_RATE (currency1, currency2, price)
    SELECT name, p_currency, price/p_price
    FROM CURRENCY
    WHERE NAME != p_current;

    INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_RATE (currency1, currency2, price)
    SELECT  p_currency, name, p_price/price
    FROM CURRENCY
    WHERE name != p_currency;
END;
```

Comment: Good idea, but the `INSERT...SELECT` statements have issues. There is no `price` column in the `CURRENCY` table. Also there is no `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT`, so even if that worked that would insert many lines in `EXCHANGE_RATE`.

Comment: good catch, I forgot to add where clause. By the way, I believe that he wants multiple inserts. IF the currency table contains 3 currencies, when the insert is made, there would be 6 different currencies is needed to be inserted (as far as I understand) :)

Comment: Sorry Simonare but you are mixing things a little. `NAME != p_price` ? Also, as I said, there is no `price` column in the `CURRENCY` table... I believe this code would not compile.